# Two way binding is not working on userModel

Tags: angular

When typing on the text boxes, Angulars form values change, but userModel values  do not change, always showing  'Vino','New street','Cairo','Alaska','343343','vino@xyz.com', '53433234','',true in the userModel values.

[image: 1]
  [image: 2]
  [image: 3]

Comment: Please add the code that you are trying to work on and point out the issue that you are facing. This will help the SO community to answer your question.

Comment: Check the answer and normally you should paste the code instead of screen-shots.

Answer (score 0):

In your app.component.ts file you have the userModel as an array, you should declare it as an object. like this:

```
this.userModel = {

}
```

> In your app.component.ts file you should import user class, assign the type of userModel as User and then in the constructor or ngOnInit() method instantiate User class with respective properties like this:

```
import { User } from './user'; //(this will be the path as per your file structure)

userModel: User; // userModel like this

constructor() {
  // assigning initial value to userModel
  this.userModel = new User(
    this.name, "street", "city", "start", 1234, "timePreference", true
  );

  console.log(this.userModel);
}
```

Here's a LIVE EXAMPLE: [CLICK HERE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-klojpq)